# get Specific columns in Spring

Tags: laravel, orm, spring-data-jpa, with-statement

When I call the findAll() function in the result I get all the relation so I need to select the same columns.
In Laravel they are used with()  to resolve problm so What is the equivalent of the Laravel function in spring boot

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Spring Data Jpa Projections. You can create a interface for specific columns that you want to bring from db. And then you can give this Interface projection as type to your repository method.

You can see the example from here
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections#interface-based-projections